# How to write a decorator for asynchronous functions

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I wrote a decorator for asynchronous functions, but it does't work - an assertion is not thrown. Where is an error?
The code in attachment.

```
import asyncio
import pytest

def tmi_freq_check(needed_value: int, tmi_freq_tolerance: int, tmi_freq_critical: bool, info_message: str = ""):
    def decorator(func):
        @functools.wraps(func)
        async def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            result = await func(*args, **kwargs)
            if tmi_freq_critical:
                assert needed_value == pytest.approx(result, tmi_freq_tolerance)
            return result

        return wrapper

    return decorator


@tmi_freq_check(600, 10, True)
async def my_function():
    return 500


async def main():
    await my_function()

asyncio.run(main())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your decorator works and the underlying assertion passes.
But the issue is in *tolerance* parameter. It's not really a simple diff between two arguments but a ***relative tolerance***.

From `pytest.approx` [doc](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/reference/reference.html#pytest.approx):

> **Tolerances**
>
> By default, approx considers numbers within a relative tolerance of
> `1e-6` (i.e. one part in a million) of its expected value to be equal.
> This treatment would lead to surprising results if the expected value
> was 0.0, because nothing but 0.0 itself is relatively close to 0.0. To
> handle this case less surprisingly, `approx` also considers numbers
> within an absolute tolerance of `1e-12` of its expected value to be
> equal. Infinity and NaN are special cases. Infinity is only considered
> equal to itself, regardless of the relative tolerance. NaN is not
> considered equal to anything by default, but you can make it be equal
> to itself by setting the nan_ok argument to True. (This is meant to
> facilitate comparing arrays that use NaN to mean “no data”.)
>
> ...

In your case: `10` is `0.02` part of `500` and should be specified in that pattern:

```
@tmi_freq_check(600, 2e-2, True)
async def my_function():
    return 500
```

---

Now, the it's seen that the relative threshold is exceeded:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
    assert needed_value == pytest.approx(result, tmi_freq_tolerance)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AssertionError
```